# Find out OS via react-native-web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have already searched the whole internet for the question in the title, but have not found anything.
I am using react native web with expo and trying to find out which operating system the users of a web application are using.

I came across the Platform.OS function, but this function does NOT solve the problem I just described. Platform.OS returns 'web' for both Android and IOS.

```
btw I'm using: 
react-native-version: 0.64.1
expo version: 40.0.0
react-native-web version: 0.16.2
```

Comment: You want something like Linux OS or version too like (Ubuntu, Kali Linux etc ) ?

Comment: that would be a nice to have, but is not a must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of Platform.OS is to distinguish between devices (like iOS, android and web).

You might want to look at react-native-device-info : https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info

There is a lot of methods there to get some informations on the device that is running your app.
A lot of methods are not supported on the web, and you have a table on the documentation explaining what is supported or not for each device.

You could use `getBaseOs()` though, for example on my RN web project it would return `Mac OS`, you won't get the full OS version with this though.

You could also use `getUseAgent()` which would give you somethings like this: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 (but this will be different for each browser).`

Comment: thanks, this is exaclty what I was looking for.